# Pycharm Install Github Private Repo Package ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name'

Tags: python, github, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

I have tried to install a private Github repo package into Pycharm, and ran into a ModuleNotFoundError. I replaced actual package name with generic package_name for convenience of the reader.

I've gotten it to work on my Travis with a Pipfile and an environment variable of CI_USER_TOKEN.

However, here's what I've tried to make it work locally, and I haven't gotten progress in the last couple of hours of working on this:

1. I put that CI_USER_TOKEN into an .env file locally, and created a .netrc file in the home directory with the GitHub credentials, and still no luck. (Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name')
2. I also set the CI_USER_TOKEN as an environmental variable in the edit configurations section of the open 'edit run/debug run configurations' dialog. (Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name')
3. I also added my Github account on the preferences > Version Control > GitHub using the CI_USER_TOKEN key. (Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name')
4. Lastly, I tried to set it as an installable from in the preferences > project interpreter > Install (plus sign) > Manage Repositories > Enter Repository URL (Error: "Error loading package list: Request failed with status code 404")

So I'm stumped on why Pycharm is so much harder to configure with installing a private repo than Travis/Pipfile is for the same repo. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction because I feel like I'm spinning my wheels.

Comment: How did you install this private Github repo package?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Pycharm settings and choose "Project: <your_project> -> Python Interpreter". Make sure the selected python interpreter is the one where you actually installed your package and you will be able to import it in pycharm. If you can activate that environment (with virtualenv, conda, etc) and import your module from the python terminal outside pycharm, then it will work in pycharm as long as the selected interpreter is correct.

Comment: I'm seeing that my python interpreter is coming up with issues pointing to the right dir, where the python is in anaconda, Pipenv in anaconda, but the Pycharm is pointed elsewhere. I'll have to debug that as I have a dozen different python locations

Comment: Pycharm supports differentes environments, including regular virtualenv and conda environments. You should be able to select the correct project interpreter in pycharm. It can support other types too such as [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) environments, if you install a plugin.